# Angular text interpolation with a condition

Tags: angular

I am trying to use Angular interpolation with a condition. When I want to use a value from my component as one of the condition options, it only displays the text not the value being interpolated. Specifically, the term **available_items** is not being interpolated. How can I interpolate a value as one of the options in this condition?

**component.ts**

```
public available_items = 10;
```

**component.html**

```
<!--Does not work-->
<ul *ngFor="let key of keys">
    <li
        title="{{values[key]}} Node{{values[key] > 1 ? 's' : ''}}{{visibleItems[key] !== 1 ? ' (only {{available_items }} available)' : ''}}">
    </li>
</ul>

<!--works!-->
<ul *ngFor="let key of keys">
    <li
        className="caption-row"
        title="{{values[key]}} Node{{values[key] > 1 ? 's' : ''}}{{visibleItems[key] !== 1 ? ' (only 10 available)' : ''}}">
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: your code doesn't make any sense to me. what does your data look like? how is keys related to values? and what is visibleItems?  maybe you want something more like this?: `*ngFor="let key of values"`

Comment: Hi Rick, the question was more about the interpolation than the data. I have updated the question to make it clearer. I don't seem to be able to interpolate even a single value inside the condition.

Comment: my guess is that is due to your value being nested inside a single quote, which is nested inside a double quote. interpolation worked inside the double-quote, but the single quote probably makes it a literal. just a guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ul *ngFor="let key of keys">
    <li
        title="{{values[key]}} Node{{values[key] > 1 ? 's' : ''}}{{visibleItems[key] !== 1 ? ' (only ' + visibleItems[key] + ' available)' : ''}}">
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is everything in the single quote is a literal. try this:

```
<ul *ngFor="let key of keys">
<li
    title="{{values[key]}} Node{{values[key] > 1 ? 's' : ''}}{{visibleItems[key] !== 1 ? ' (only '+ available_items+' available)' : ''}}">
</li>
```

Comment: This is correct, I chose the answer from Mojtaba Nejad Poor Esmaeili as it was a little bit quicker